# Expected value of a function that is not sampled uniformly

Tags: expected-value, independence, mean

How can I calculate the expected value of a random variable $R(\Omega)$,   when the samples  are not i.i.d? In my specific case, I have more samples at lower values of the parameter of the function, but less samples as the parameter increases.

For example,

[image: Plot of R and omega]

Note that  $\Omega = {0 \dots 1}$

More concretely, I would like to estimate the expected value of the population ($E( R(\Omega)$), marginalizing over $\Omega$.  This is usually trivial in the i.i.d case, as it can be computed by the mean of the sample.  However, in my case I have many more samples at lower values, than in higher values.

Should I weight the samples according to the number of samples I have?  Or should I correct the bias in a different way?

Comment: you have to explain what you are actually trying to calculate- so be concrete and explain the problem:) . It is only biased if your sampling doesn't reflect the true probabilities. eg if I sample my friends ages, they are likely to be "biased" around my age, but thats still a correct estimate of my friends ages

Comment: @seanv507 Thanks for the feedback. I added an example of how my function may look like. Hope it is more clear!

Comment: The question is whether your sample reflects the population that you are trying to estimate or not: if your population also has many more low values then there is no need to correct the bias. If you explain the physical problem you are trying to solve it will be clearer

Comment: To answer explicitly your question, if my data was collected differently, I would see samples more "uniformly" distributed over $\Omega$.  Does this make sense?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horvitz%E2%80%93Thompson_estimator will give you a start on a solution.